# List Kafka Topics via Spring-Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We would like to list all Kafka topics via spring-kafka to get results similar to the kafka command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

When running the getTopics() method in the service below, we get **org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata**

Configuration:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:2181");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
            StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
            StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class TopicServiceKafkaImpl implements TopicService {
    @Autowired
    private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory;

    @Override
    public Set<String> getTopics() {
        try (Consumer<String, String> consumer = 
            consumerFactory.createConsumer()) {
            Map<String, List<PartitionInfo>> map = consumer.listTopics();
            return map.keySet();
    }
}
```

Kafka is up and running and we can send messages from our app to a topic succesfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are connecting to Zookeeper (2181) instead of Kafka (9092 by default).

The Java kafka clients no longer talk directly to ZK.

Comment: Awesome. All of the tutorials / examples that I've seen talk to Zookeeper.

Comment: While pointing out the code-flaw, this doesn't really answer how to get the list of topics with spring-kafka

Comment: ?? While I haven't tested it myself, the `KafkaConsumer.listTopics()` Javadocs says `Get metadata about partitions for all topics that the user is authorized to view. This method will issue a remote call to the server.`. **all topics the user is authorized to view** seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: And `assignment()` says `Get the set of partitions currently assigned to this consumer.`.

Comment: Fair enough, though I do personally find it odd to go through the consumer and [fetcher API to get said information](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java#L278-L285)

Answer (score 9):

You can list topics like this using Admin Client

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

    AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);

    ListTopicsOptions listTopicsOptions = new ListTopicsOptions();
    listTopicsOptions.listInternal(true);

    System.out.println("topics:" + adminClient.listTopics(listTopicsOptions).names().get());
```

Answer (score 4):

`kafka-topics --list` is a shell script that just is a wrapper around [`kafka.admin.TopicCommand`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/TopicCommand.scala#L168-L177) class, where you can find the method you are looking for

Alternatively, you can also use the [`AdminClient#listTopics`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126071/2308683) method

Comment: I agree it's odd; however, I suppose if you already have a consumer, it would save opening a new connection for this purpose. I wouldn't open a new consumer just for this, though. I also wouldn't get involved with the scala client mentioned in your first sentence.